# Any benefit to loading a single image via background with CSS?

Tags: css, image, background-image, httprequest

Ok, obviously if you have a lot if icons you generally load them in via a background image so you can utilise sprites; however, I was just wondering if there is any advantage to loading them in via the background versus loading them via a `img` tag when it is just a single image?

Does the one in the CSS still make a http request for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still makes a request, unless you URL encode the image, but this you can also do inline and is not necessarily more performant.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're mostly interested in how this affects performance. But since the question is open-ended here are other reasons, for completeness:

- If you need to calculate the image's height based on its width (a common responsive design method is `width: [something > 0]; height: 0; padding-bottom: [some]%` )
- If you need to use CSS to swap out the image (basic icon example: if the image changes on `:hover` and you aren't using a sprite, for any number of reasons)
- If you need to be able to use CSS background options like `background-size` or `background-position` (IE > 8)
- If you need to have HTML on top of your image without adding an additional element
- If you need to use pseudoelements like `:before` and `:after`, which are not supported for <img> (not *required to be* supported, anyway)